# Lilypond tuplets

Tags: lilypond

[image: Triplets over two eighths and a half note]

As can be seen in the image, some composers mix the note types used in tuplets.  In this case, there are two eighths and a half note (equal to 4 eighths).  The total duration is 6 eighths in triplet time.  Thus, ignoring the last four eighth notes in the bar, the first part of the phrase could be written in Lilypond as:

```
\tuplet 3/2 {e'8 b8 g8} \tuplet 3/2 {g8 g8 g8}
```

This, however, changes the phrasing, displaying it as two sets of triplets.  Is there a way for Lilypond to produce the output as in the display?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Of course there is. Why don't you just write what you see? `\tuplet 3/2 { e'8 b8 g2 }` will do the job and give the following result:

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Some more details:

Tuplets in Lilypond are far more powerful than they are in most other notation software. A tuplet in Lilypond is essentially nothing but music with a scaling factor and a bracket above. If you set the property tupletSpan or use the optional argument `\tuplet ratio duration music` Lilypond will automatically split the tuplet into multiple tuplets of given duration. If you do not you can create tuplets of arbitrary dimensions such as this:

```
\tuplet 3/2 {
  c' d' e' f' g' a' | g' f' e' d' c' b | c'1.
}
```

Also you can do any sort of tuplets crossing measures, and even do tuplets with irregular duration:

```
{
  c'4 d' \tuplet 3/2 e' d' \tuplet 3/2 c'8 |
  d'4 \tuplet 3/2 e'2 d'8 c' \tuplet 3/2 d'4
}
```

Combine this with irregular time signatures, and you can do stuff like this:

```
\new RhythmicStaff {
  \numericTimeSignature
  \time 4/4
  \repeat unfold 4 { 8-> 8 }
  \tuplet 3/2 4 \repeat unfold 4 { 8-> 8 8 } |
  \time 4/6
  \tuplet 3/2 4*2/3 \repeat unfold 4 { 8-> 8 }
  \time 3/6
  \tuplet 3/2 4*2/3 \repeat unfold 3 { 8-> 8 }
  \time 6/12
  \tuplet 3/2 4 \repeat unfold 2 { 8-> 8 8 }
  \time 4/4
  \tuplet 3/2 4 \repeat unfold 4 { 8-> 8 8 }
  \repeat unfold 4 { 8-> 8 }
}
```

So in Lilypond you can have a Tuplet do quite arbitrary things, and doing what is seen in this excerpt is simply done by entering what you see and slapping a Tuplet onto it.

But even more even if you take a different piece of software like MuseScore (where a tuplet is music made up of n units taking the space of m units (where a unit is a power of 2 division)), which does not allow everything Lilypond would allow, will have no problems creating a tuplet such as the one you’ve shown.